# how to change the Android-camera to portrait in surfaceview?

Tags: java, android, android-camera, surfaceview

I am coding for an android tablet and i want my app to use the portrait view of the `surfaceView` camera preview. It is landscape by default, and I tried the following code to rotate to portrait view:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder){
  // The Surface has been created, acquire the camera and tell it where to draw.
  mCamera = Camera.open();
  Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
  // If we aren't landscape (the default), tell the camera we want portrait mode
  if (this.getResources().getConfiguration().orientation != Configuration.ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE){
    params.set("orientation", "portrait"); // "landscape"
    // And Rotate the final picture if possible
    // This works on 2.0 and higher only
    //params.setRotation(90);
    // Use reflection to see if it exists and to call it so you can support older versions
      try {
        Method rotateSet = Camera.Parameters.class.getMethod("setRotation", new Class[] { Integer.TYPE } );
        Object arguments[] = new Object[] { new Integer(270) };
        rotateSet.invoke(params, arguments);
      } catch (NoSuchMethodException nsme) {
        // Older Device
        Log.v("CameraView","No Set Rotation");
      } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
        Log.v("CameraView","Exception IllegalArgument");
      } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
        Log.v("CameraView","Illegal Access Exception");
      } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        Log.v("CameraView","Invocation Target Exception");
      }
  }
  mCamera.setParameters(params);
  try{
    mCamera.setPreviewDisplay(holder);
  } catch (IOException exception) {
    mCamera.release();
    mCamera = null;
  }
}
```

But it doesn't work. Could anybody fix it please?

Comment: also tried with Object arguments[] = new Object[] { new Integer(90) };    but still i could not fix it .

Comment: Since you got the surfaceview to work, can you provide me with an example. I need to stream from an ipcamera to my android and I want to use surfaceview

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will probably want to use the `setDisplayOrientation` function as follows:

```
public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 8) mCamera.setDisplayOrientation(90);
}
```

Using the camera `params.set("orientation"...` stuff is not consistent across devices and is really pre-SDK 8 language.